# Symfony 3 - some difficulties with my doctrine queryBuilder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, date, doctrine

I started on Symfony and I do not master Doctrine well.

I have entities Packages / User / PackagesDDLExterne
My Package entity corresponds to packages that the User can download.
The PackageDDLExterne entity contains id, package_id, id_user, date

My goal is to create a request with doctrine allowing me to recover the number of downloads of each package between two dates. And take into account that those who have not been downloaded will have a nbDDL of 0.

My PaquetDDLExterne :

[image]

Paquet :

[image]

In SQL it would give something like this:

```
SELECT (p.titre, count(p.id)
FROM PaquetDDLExterne pa
INNER JOIN Paquet p
WHERE (pa.package_id = p.id)
AND (pa.date between ($dateDeb) and ($dateFin))
```

Well, the query is wrong too, but it's for imaging. Basically I want to get something like:

```
Titre       nbDDL
------------------
Titre 1      12
Titre 2      48
Titre 3      0
Titre 4      15
```

Thanks for your help !

EDIT: For the moment, I've :

```
public function getPackagesDDLBetween($debut, $fin)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("p")
        ->select("pa.titre, count(p.package)")
        ->join("p.package","pa")
        ->where("p.date between :debut and :fin")
        ->groupBy("pa.id")
        ->setParameter('debut',$debut)
        ->setParameter('fin',$fin);
        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```

But with a dump, the result is null

Comment: I don't get it. The title says "symfony 3 manage form without entity assosiation", but in the post itself you're talking about SQL and there is no relevance to symfony whatsoever. Could you please change your question or title to be relevant?

Comment: Oh... Well, that was an old problem I had, and he kept the title. It's changed! And I also edited my message to add what I already did

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. Job seems to be already done. You have only forgotten a closing parenthesis and you should have a `groupBy("pa.titre")` instead of a `groupBy("pa.id") `

Comment: Yes, I changed my groupBy("pa.id") by groupBy("pa.titre"). But I have a null result :/
What id the date format that I have to use ?

Comment: It's okay now, It works ! Thanks ;)

Comment: can you dump the sql of your query like this `dump($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSql());`